# How to get secrets from AWS Secrets manager in EKS using CSI driver

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-secrets-manager, eksctl, k8s-serviceaccount

Hi I am working on a POC, where I have to bring Secrets form AWS secrets manager in a EKS Pod, But I am getting this error.

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store-inline" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod default/busyboxsecret, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to fetch secret from all regions: arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-south-1:121000000000:secret:test/secret-ihX9W4
```

[How to access your AWS Secret Manager secrets in an Elastic Kubernetes Service cluster [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZPgD.png)]

I am following this documentation as referance:
(https://binx.io/2021/11/03/how-to-access-your-aws-secret-manager-secrets-in-an-elastic-kubernetes-service-cluster/)

I tried the below things:
My serviceAccount.yml file looks as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: secret-manager-service-account
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::121000000000:role/eksctl-sandbox-addon-iamserviceaccount-defau-Role1-M5ALRCJ7CZ8E
```

My SecretProviderClass.yml file is as below:

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: secrets-provider
spec:
  provider: aws
  secretObjects:
    - secretName: testsecret
      type: Opaque
      data:
        - objectName: "MySecretPassword"
          key: password
  parameters:
    objects: |
      - objectName: arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-south-1:121756462868:secret:test/secret-ihX9W4
        objectAlias: "MySecretPassword"
```

and my podDefinition.yml file is as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busyboxsecret
  labels:
    name: busybox
    app: busybox
spec:
  serviceAccountName: secret-manager-service-account
  containers:
  - name: busyboxsecret
    image: busybox
    # resources:
    #   limits:
    #     memory: "128Mi"
    #     cpu: "500m"
    command: 
      - "sleep"
      - "3600"
    volumeMounts:
    - name: secrets-store-inline
      mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
      readOnly: true
    env:
    - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: testsecret # Name of the secret in Kubernetes Secrets, which has been set in the secretProviderClass 
          key: password
  volumes:
  - name: secrets-store-inline
    csi:
      driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
      readOnly: true
      volumeAttributes:
        secretProviderClass: "secrets-provider"
```

And EKS service role contains following permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "kms:CallerAccount": [
                        "AWS_ACCOUNT_ID"
                    ],
                    "kms:ViaService": [
                        "secretsmanager.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust relationship:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::121000000000:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/id/E0A69D78D61DE240EB05F3266AB90640"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/id/E0A69D78D61DE240EB05F3266AB90640:sub": "system:serviceaccount:default:secret-store-service-account",
                    "oidc.eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/id/E0A69D78D61DE240EB05F3266AB90640:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong in here. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use jmes path syntax to fetch the specific key values from AWS secret manager in the SecretProviderClass manifest.

For eg:

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: secrets-provider
spec:
  provider: aws
  secretObjects:
    - secretName: testsecret
      type: Opaque
      data:
        - objectName: "MySecretPassword"
          key: password
  parameters:
    objects: |
      - objectName: arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-south-1:121756462868:secret:test/secret-ihX9W4
        objectAlias: "MySecretPassword"
        objectType: "secretsmanager" 
        jmesPath: 
          - path: password  # <key-from-secretmanager> 
            objectAlias: password
```